# How to use the setInput method to specify an InputStream?

Tags: android, xml, inputstream

I want to write to an XML file in the SD card. I found this code and i have no idea how to make it work with an InputStream.

```
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.StringReader;

     import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
     import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException.html;
     import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

     public class SimpleXmlPullApp
     {

         public static void main (String args[])
             throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
         {
             XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
             factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
             XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

             xpp.setInput(new StringReader ("<foo>Hello World!</foo>"));
             int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
             while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
              if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                  System.out.println("Start document");
              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                  System.out.println("End document");
              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                  System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                  System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                  System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
              }
              eventType = xpp.next();
             }
         }
     }
```

This is the path to my xml file:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DataLog.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

It's a step by step guide on how to use the xml pull parser, It's what I used to learn to use it.

And for creating an input stream use

`String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DataLog.xml";`
`FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);`